# check string in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

it is really angular JS foreign to me. I am looking colleague code now. 
I need to text, if text has `"Loading data"` then print something.

```
<div id="messageContainer">
        <label m></label>
        {{message}}
    </div>
```

I need like

```
`If({{message}}.Contains('Loading data')
           <FONT style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow">{{message}}</FONT>.  
else
       {{message}}
```

how to do that?

Comment: Check out ng-if directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` directive to conditionally show/hide the html elements on the page. But you can improvise your code by using `ng-class` directive to add the required conditional styles through css classes. Something like this.

Css

```
.loading {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="msg" ng-class="{loading: message.indexOf('Loading data') !== -1}">
 {{message}}
</div>
```

Comment: @ShakarSangoli, I need other way round. if contains show yellow if not show normal

Comment: If the message contains `Loading data` it will add the loading class and show the background with yellow color.

Answer (score 0):

using ng-class:

CSS :

```
 .basic{
     background-color:white;
 }
 .yellow{
     background-color:yellow;
 }
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-class="{'yellow': message.indexOf('Loading data') !== -1 , 'basic': message.indexOf('Loading data') === -1 }" ></div>
```